# WebMatrix Razor - Must declare the scalar variable "@0"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been searching for two days now and can not figure this one out.  I am new to using Razor.  I keep getting the following error no matter what I try.  Basically I am trying to pull data from a database and render a chart (works).  Then I also want a drop down menu so the user can select a specific point to look at and have it render the new chart.
Here is the top code:

```
    @{  var db = Database.Open("telecommConnectionString"); 
     var data = db.Query("select distinct employees.cost_center, costcenters.costcenterdesc from    dbo.invoices, dbo.employees, dbo.costcenters where invoices.emp_id = employees.emp_id and employees.supervisor = '11111111' and employees.cost_center = costcenters.costcenterid group by costcenterdesc,cost_center, bill_date");

var categories = data.Select(categorieslist =>new SelectListItem {
     Value = categorieslist.cost_center.ToString(),
     Text = categorieslist.costcenterdesc
 });
var filename="~MCCE2.jpg";
var cat = "";   
  if(!IsPost){

var dbdata = db.Query("select a.bill_date, a.costcenterdesc, a.total from (select invoices.bill_date, sum(invoices.total_current) as total, costcenters.costcenterdesc from dbo.invoices, dbo.employees, dbo.costcenters where invoices.emp_id = employees.emp_id and employees.supervisor = '11111111' and employees.cost_center = costcenters.costcenterid group by costcenterdesc, bill_date)a"); 

 var myChart = new Chart(width: 800, height: 500, theme: ChartTheme.Blue) 
.AddTitle("Count of Employees by Carrier") 
.AddLegend()
.DataBindCrossTable(dbdata, groupByField:"costcenterdesc", xField:"bill_date", yFields:"total")
.Save(filename);

 }

 if(IsPost){

     cat=Request.Form["costcenter"];
 var dbdata =  db.Query("select invoices.bill_date, sum(invoices.total_current) as total, costcenters.costcenterdesc from dbo.invoices, dbo.employees, dbo.costcenters where invoices.emp_id = employees.emp_id and employees.supervisor = '11111111' and employees.cost_center = costcenters.costcenterid and costcenters.costcenterid = @0 group by costcenterdesc, bill_date"); 

 var myChart = new Chart(width: 800, height: 500, theme: ChartTheme.Yellow) 
.AddTitle("Count of Employees by Carrier") 
.AddLegend()
.DataBindCrossTable(dbdata, groupByField:"costcenterdesc", xField:"bill_date", yFields:"total")
.Save(filename);
 }
 }
```

and here is my HTML to call the dropdown and chart:

```
 <form method="post" action="MCCE2">
        Select Cost Center:
         @Html.DropDownList("costcenter", "--Choose Your Cost Center--", categories )
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

      <p>     
    </br>
    <img src="@Href(filename)" alt="@Href(filename)"/>
```

Here is the error that I get no matter what I try:

Exception Details:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@0".

Line 32:  var dbdata =  db.Query("select invoices.bill_date, sum(invoices.total_current) as total, costcenters.costcenterdesc from dbo.invoices, dbo.employees, dbo.costcenters where invoices.emp_id = employees.emp_id and employees.supervisor = '11111111' and employees.cost_center = costcenters.costcenterid and costcenters.costcenterid = @0 group by costcenterdesc, bill_date");
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have in your WHERE clause of the SQL:

```
costcenters.costcenterid = @0
```

Did you mean that, or did you mean to pass in zero, or in fact did you mean for this to be a parameter which you set (but may have forgotten to)?

I presume you want to pass in the category selected:

```
cat=Request.Form["costcenter"];
```

Which you haven't done.  The code would need to change to:

```
var dbdata =  db.Query("select invoices.bill_date, sum(invoices.total_current) as total, costcenters.costcenterdesc from dbo.invoices, dbo.employees, dbo.costcenters where invoices.emp_id = employees.emp_id and employees.supervisor = '11111111' and employees.cost_center = costcenters.costcenterid and costcenters.costcenterid = @0 group by costcenterdesc, bill_date", cat);
```

Comment: Thank you... I did miss that last part and now is working perfectly.